# I used version 14.3.1 of next .js and it gives Hydration failed error And it says your version is old

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

[image]

It is interesting here that I have even deleted all the code sections, but with a refech, it first displays the deleted content, then the error, and then the new page changes.

I feel more that it is from the next .js version than the problem of my code

These are the codes I use:

```js
"use client"
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {RiMenu3Line} from "react-icons/ri";
import {
    BsFillBusFrontFill,
    BsFillCupHotFill,
    BsFillPaletteFill,
    BsFillPinFill,
    BsFillRocketTakeoffFill, BsFillSignpost2Fill
} from "react-icons/bs";

const Page = () => {
    const [hiddenMenu, setHiddenMenu] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-row gap-3 bg-gray-100">
            <div className={`bg-gray-300/50 min-h-screen z-20 rounded overflow-hidden ${hiddenMenu ? "w-16" : "w-80"}`}>
                <div className=" p-3 flex flex-col gap-4">
                    <div><BsFillBusFrontFill size={25}/>
                    </div>
                    <div><BsFillCupHotFill size={25}/>
                    </div>
                    <div><BsFillPaletteFill size={25}/>
                    </div>
                    <div><BsFillPinFill size={25}/>
                    </div>
                    <div><BsFillRocketTakeoffFill size={25}/>
                    </div>
                    <div><BsFillSignpost2Fill size={25}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 w-full ml-3 ">
                <div className="bg-gray-500 p-3 mt-3 rounded flex flex-row justify-between">
                    <div onClick={() => {
                        setHiddenMenu(!hiddenMenu)
                    }}><RiMenu3Line size={25}/></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div className="bg-gray-300 min-h-screen rounded">content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Page;
```